# Active textarea causing layout issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, textarea

I have a contact form on a Wordpress site that functionally does what is supposed to do, but when I click on the textarea to write my message it "jumps" down over the submit button and destroys the whole layout. For functionality of the form I use Contact forms 7 Wordpress plugin. The issue occurs both on Chrome and Firefox. I Commented out code line by line and it seems like the width:100%; is causing the issue.

(link to the [website](http://exit.si/khtYL))

screenshots:

[contact form without the textarea active](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMTOc.png)

[when the textarea is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57HC0.png)

Structure of the form.

```
 <div class="forma">
   <span class="naslov">Feel free to use the form to contact me</span>
   [text* your-name placeholder "Name"]
   [email* your-email placeholder "Your email address"]
   [text your-subject placeholder "Subject"]
   [textarea* message id:contact-message 10x5 placeholder "Your Message"]
   [submit "Send"]
  </div>
```

CSS that causes issues

```
.forma input, .forma textarea {
    width:100%;
    padding:10px;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    resize:none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family:GT-Walsheim-Pro-Regular;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Preferably as a snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I edited out the unnecessary CSS. For example of unwanted behaviour, I added a link to the website where it is occuring, screenshots and also tried to describe the issue as close as possible can. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is solved now? OK.

Comment: No, I'm saying that I've put more effort into explaining the issue itself, and not just pasted a bunch of unrelated code.

Comment: In that case, sorry but I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Fixed, the issue was occurring because I was using Chrome Canary build.

Comment: Oh... I can't reproduce the problem with the Canary either. Version 65.0.3314.0. Something else must be going on. That said, if you see something wrong in the Canary that is working fine in the normal release, saying "Oh, no problem then" might not be a good idea. It might very well mean it has new features or new error handling that will make it into the normal release soon!